# Dagger 2 - Null Pointer in Field Injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am using dagger 2 for dependency injection and got stuck with **field injection**. Below is the complete scenario with code sample:

Let's say we have a class A which depends on a library B

```
class A {
    @Inject
    B b;
}
```

Module for B:

```
@Module
public class BModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public B provideB() {
        return new C.methodA();
        // C - static class; C.methodA returns B

    }
}
```

But when I try to use `b` in class A then I get null pointer exception but if I do the same using **constructor injection** then it works perfectly.
I can assure that component and other dependencies are fine as the constructor part works correctly.

A is a dependency of some other class (let's call X) and A is being initialized using constructor injection (tested). Also, X is being injected as `void inject(X x);`

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there anything I am missing out for field injection due to which it is not being injected?
2. I am able to successfully compile the code and get runtime exception, but dagger2 is compile-time DI then why is it unable to catch this while compiling?

P.S.: I have just shared a part of the code as there are multiple dependencies, so just trying to explain the scenario. Let me know if the question/scenario is still unclear or needs more info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Field injection in `dagger` is a bit more complicated than constructor injection. When you use constructor injection like this

```
class A {
    @Inject
    public A(B b) {}
}
```

and you have provider for class B

```
@Module
class DaggerModule {
    @Provides
    B provideB() {}
}
```

now dagger will know how to create instance of `A` and pass it required constructor parameter. So everything is fine, compile successfully and works perfect.

But if we speak about field injection

```
class A {
    @Inject
    B b;
}
```

and have somewhere provider for `B`, dagger can't know how to create `A` instance and when inject `b` property (in case of manually creating instance of `A` by hand). To make it work you need write special method in component

```
@Component(DaggetModule.class)
interface DaggerComponent {
    void inject(A a);
}
```

and somewhere in code

```
A a = new A();
DaggerComponent component = //TODO getDaggerComponent()
component.inject(a);
```

After that `b` property will be initialized and available for later usage. Hope, it's clear now how to make field injection work.

Comment: Thanks @ConstOrVar, I forgot to mention here that A is a dependency of some other class (let's call X) and A is being initialized correctly. Also, X is being initialized as you have suggested i.e. void inject(X x); I will update in the question as well.